# MySQLI error mysqli_connect

Tags: php, mysql

Line number 7 returns this error:

> php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known.

```
<?php
define("HOST", "###"); // The host you want to connect to. 
define("USER", "###"); // The database username. 
define("PASSWORD", "###"); // The database password. 
define("DATABASE", "###"); // The database name. 

$dbconnect = new mysqli(HOST, USER, PASSWORD, DATABASE);
if($dbconnect->connect_error) {
    die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '. mysqli_connect_error());
}
mysqli_set_charset($dbconnect, "utf8_unicode_ci");
?>
```

Comment: Read their documentation.

Comment: I hope for your sake that those aren't your actual credentials.

Comment: Change those credentials as soon as possible on your SQL server, you just exposed them.

Comment: I have changed them.

Comment: @MarkusMoltke All nice and dandy, but I hope you changed them on the server also. That's the most important.

Comment: I have done that too :)

Comment: ^ Good! Next time/question, replace credentials with `xxx`.

Answer (score 0):

That means that mysql can't connect to the host (mysql.hostinger.dk) for some reason. Make sure that you have the right address and that mysql is running on the server.

Answer (score 0):

mysql.hostinger.dk can't be resolved to an IP.

try doing `ping mysql.hostinger.dk` it should fail also

are you trying to connect to a remote mysql?

Comment: I am trying to connect to an external mysql server from my Xampp server

Comment: it looks like you can't access the mysql server from outside of the hostinger servers -  which is pretty normal for a shared hosting environment

Comment: Is there any way to do this?